# Oracle: Select rows when value in one column changes

Tags: sql, oracle, date, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```
 PLACE       USER_ID Date
---------- ---------- -----------------------------
        ABC      4     14/04/20 12:05:29,255000000  
        ABC      4     14/04/20 15:42:28,389000000  
        ABC      4     14/04/20 18:33:20,202000000  
        ABC      4     14/04/20 22:51:28,339000000    
        XYZ      4     14/04/20 11:07:23,335000000     
        XYZ      2     14/04/20 12:15:12,123000000    
        ABC      4     13/04/20 22:09:33,255000000   
        QWE      4     13/04/20 10:18:29,144000000 
        XYZ      2     14/04/20 10:05:47,255000000
```

And I need to get the rows when the place changes order by date for the user_id that I select.
**So the desired result should be this (for user_id 4):**

```
 PLACE       USER_ID           DATE
---------- ---------- -----------------------------
        ABC      4     14/04/20 12:05:29,255000000     
        XYZ      4     14/04/20 11:07:23,335000000 
        ABC      4     13/04/20 22:09:33,255000000    
        QWE      4     13/04/20 10:18:29,144000000
```

I tried with min date but in my example, I lose data if the user goes back to that place:

```
 SELECT MIN(DATE), PLACE FROM user_places WHERE USER_ID=4 GROUP BY PLACE
```

**Result I get (missing one row):**

```
 PLACE       USER_ID           DATE
---------- ---------- -----------------------------
        XYZ      4     14/04/20 11:07:23,335000000 
        ABC      4     13/04/20 22:09:33,255000000    
        QWE      4     13/04/20 10:18:29,144000000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, gaps-and-islands problems like this one are an easy task for the `match_recognize` clause. For example:

**Table setup**

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd/mm/rr hh24:mi:ss,ff';

create table user_places (place, user_id, date_) as 
  select 'ABC', 4, to_timestamp('14/04/20 12:05:29,255000000') from dual union all  
  select 'ABC', 4, to_timestamp('14/04/20 15:42:28,389000000') from dual union all  
  select 'ABC', 4, to_timestamp('14/04/20 18:33:20,202000000') from dual union all
  select 'ABC', 4, to_timestamp('14/04/20 22:51:28,339000000') from dual union all
  select 'XYZ', 4, to_timestamp('14/04/20 11:07:23,335000000') from dual union all
  select 'XYZ', 2, to_timestamp('14/04/20 12:15:12,123000000') from dual union all
  select 'ABC', 4, to_timestamp('13/04/20 22:09:33,255000000') from dual union all
  select 'QWE', 4, to_timestamp('13/04/20 10:18:29,144000000') from dual union all
  select 'XYZ', 2, to_timestamp('14/04/20 10:05:47,255000000') from dual
;

commit;
```

**Query and output**

```
select place, user_id, date_
from   (select * from user_places where user_id = 4)
match_recognize (
  order    by date_
  all rows per match
  pattern  (a {- b* -} )
  define   b as place = a.place
)
order by date_ desc   --   if needed
;

PLACE  USER_ID  DATE_
-----  -------  ---------------------------
ABC          4  14/04/20 12:05:29,255000000
XYZ          4  14/04/20 11:07:23,335000000
ABC          4  13/04/20 22:09:33,255000000
QWE          4  13/04/20 10:18:29,144000000
```

A few things to note here:

- `DATE` is a reserved keyword. Not a good column name. I used `DATE_`
  instead; notice the trailing underscore.
- I hardcoded the value **4**. Of course, the better practice is to make that into a *bind variable*.
- If you really only need to do this for one `user_id` at a time, it is most efficient to do what I did - filter the rows first, in a subquery. However, if you need to do this for all user id's in the same query, you don't need a subquery; you select from the table itself, and you need to add `partition by user_id` right at the top of the `match_recognize` clause, before `order by date_`.

Comment: This `match recognize` clause really seems like a powerful feature (althouh, somehow unfortunately, that's highly Oracle specific). I think I remember a graph-walking solution where you used that, but here in this simple case it is easier to follow. +1 for that.

Comment: Thank you, @mathguy it does exactly what I want. 

In my case I use "fecha" (spanish for date) for my column but when I asked the question, I translated the column names. 

I have a problem when using this query in a prepared statement though, get an error that says "ora-00907 missing right parenthesis" but it works well on sql developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` in a subquery to retrieve the "previous" place, and then filter on rows where the previous place is different that the current place:

```
select place, user_id, date
from (
    select t.*, lag(place) over(partition by user_id order by date) lag_place
    from mytable t
) t
where lag_place is null or place <> lag_place
```

This gives you the expected output for all users. If you want only for user 4, then you can filter in the subquery (and there is no need to `partition by` user):

```
select place, user_id, date
from (
    select t.*, lag(place) over(order by date) lag_place
    from mytable t
    where user_id = 4
) t
where lag_place is null or place <> lag_place
```

Comment: The OP requested the output for a single `user_id`, value 4. This can be fixed with a `where` clause. It is best to put that clause in the subquery - there is no point in partitioning and ordering **all** the rows if only a small subset is needed, and it's not clear that the optimizer would push the predicate in this case. And, of course, with that filter in the subquery, it will no longer be necessary to partition by user_id, since there will be only one user_id anyway.

Comment: @mathguy: fair enough. I added another query to my answer.

Comment: thank you @GMB It worked well but I realized that it's slightly slower than mathguy 's answer.

Comment: @NicoleC: it's all good. I like mathgy's answer too (I upvoted it).